Stacks Editor says plain text, but code formatting isn't plain text
Stacks Editor says plain text, but code formatting isn't plain text:

Screenshot taken on https://meta.stackexchange.com/
Markdown:
> **To create a reviewers' Custom Max Papers after having run Paper Matching Setup, you can do the following:**
>
> 1. If you have not done so, you will need to [install and instantiate the openreview-py client](https://docs.openreview.net/getting-started/using-the-api/installing-and-instantiating-the-python-client).
>
> 2. Create an Edge object with proper params as in the example below:
>
> ```
> # For Reviewers
> client.post_edge(openreview.api.Edge(
>     invitation='<your_venue_id>/Reviewers/-/Custom_Max_Papers',
>     head='<your_venue_id>/Reviewers',
>     tail='~Profile_ID1',
>     signatures=['<your_venue_id>/Program_Chairs'],
>     weight=2
> ))
> ```
>
> ```
> # For Area Chairs
> client.post_edge(openreview.api.Edge(
>     invitation='<your_venue_id>/Area_Chairs/-/Custom_Max_Papers',
>     head='<your_venue_id>/Area_Chairs',
>     tail='~Profile_ID1',
>     signatures=['<your_venue_id>/Program_Chairs'],
>     weight=2
> ))
> ```
>
> Please make sure the tail value is the profile id of the user. To get the profile id you can use the following call:
>
> ```
> profile = openreview.tools.get_profile('role@icml.cc')
> profile.id
> ```


hm, the editor looks different in different places - is this SO or SOfT? It dosen't match what we have here, and we've got 2 variations here itself?

@JourneymanGeek https://meta.stackexchange.com/

huh, coulda sworn I'd opted into the new editor.
